# Troubles with ObservableCollection<T> in Silverlight client

Tags: c#, wcf, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I've got a solution with a WPF client, a WCF service and a Silverlight Client (SL 4).

The WPF client works smoothly but the Silverlight is acting up on a point which I'm not sure how to handle it.

These are snippets of the code I have in Silverlight:

```
using sl_HFClient.svc;

namespace sl_HFClient
{
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    svc.IhfsvcClient dataSrv = new svc.IhfsvcClient();
    ObservableCollection<svc.ReasonData> reasonData;
}
```

This is to set everything up, next comes the call to the service:

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataSrv.wcGetReasonsCompleted += ReasonsLoaded;
        dataSrv.wcGetReasonsAsync();
    }
```

And at last, the code to get the collection and bind it to a combobox:

```
    private void ReasonsLoaded(object sender, wcGetReasonsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        reasonData = e.Result;
    }
```

However, this returns the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'sl_HFClient.svc.ReasonData[]' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'

I'm quite new to Silverlight and C#, I've done some things with SL4 and VB.NET before and
by comparing this code with a VB.NET project it seems to work.

What am I doing wrong??

//JaggenSWE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
private void ReasonsLoaded(object sender, wcGetReasonsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    reasonData = new ObservableCollection<ReasonData>(e.Result);
}
```

Not entirely sure if this will work in Silverlight, but the solution nonetheless is to explicitly create a new `ObservableCollection<ReasonData>` instead of trying to implicitly cast from an `ReasonData[]`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, worked like a charm. :) Explicit and Implicit casting is something that comes in 2 chapters in the book I'm reading on c# atm. :)